# Transit through US for Indian travelers during Covid

Tags: india, covid-19, visa, travel

An [order](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2021/05/06/2021-09711/suspension-of-entry-as-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting) was passed by the US government restricting travel to the USA, for non-US-citizens who have been physically present in India in the 14 days prior to their arrival in the USA.

This question is about interpreting the following exception in [Section 2. a) viii)](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2021-09711/p-16) :

*any noncitizen traveling as a nonimmigrant pursuant to a C-1, D, or C-1/D nonimmigrant visa as a crewmember or any noncitizen otherwise traveling to the United
States as air or sea crew;*

I have the following three related questions:

Q1: Does this exception apply to any non-immigrant with a C-1 visa, or only those non-immigrants who serve as crew?

Q2: The part of the clause before the first *or* would imply that anyone can transit with a C-1 visa. Is this interpretation correct?

Q3: According to [this page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html), nonimmigrants with a B visa can transit through the US and do not need a separate C visa. Would Section 2. a) viii) then also allow any non-immigrant with a B visa to transit through the US?

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: Is that the reason why you downvoted the question? As per policy, questions that are poorly framed, are unclear, that do not show research effort or are not useful deserve a downvote. Can you explain your rationale for the downvote?

Comment: Other question has been deleted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This would be better answered on law than on travel In any case it is surely on-topic for law and should not be closed as off-topic, nor migrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part can be parsed as:

> (any noncitizen traveling as a nonimmigrant pursuant to a C-1, D, or
> C-1/D nonimmigrant visa as a crewmember) **or** (any noncitizen otherwise
> traveling to the United States as air or sea crew)

where either the first part has to be true, or the second. Being a crew member is a requirement of both of the options. It is not true that "*Anyone* can transit with a C-1 visa": you must also be a crew member.

Since the rule does not state an exception for a B visa holder, a B-visa holder may not avail themselves of the "transit / crew" exception. The State department suggestion simply means that you can also transit with a B visa. A C visa is not equivalent to a B visa.